# Wm- concat not working as expected on nullable columns

Tags: aggregation, wm-concat

We are using older oracle version. listagg is not an option.

I want to use wm_concat  on a nullable column to get comma separated fax numbers for the same supplier. it's not working as expected

Wm-concat  works fine on non nullable column but not on nullable one what could be the reason. I am even  checking for is not null in my where clause. I am not getting expected output  it's always returning null.